# Storing an alphanumeric string in 4 32bit integers

Tags: php, encoding, binary

Following on from my previous question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610196/storing-an-alphanumeric-message-in-4-32bit-integers), how can refactor the following (awful but working POC) code to only support integers between 0 and 2147483647?

```
<?php   
$lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$upper = strtoupper($lower);
$numbers = '1234567890';
$chars = $upper.$lower.$numbers;

$map = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($chars); $i++) {
    $map[$chars{$i - 1}] = $i;
}
$map[' '] = count($map) + 1;

function map($char)
{
    global $map;

    return $map[$char];
}

function encode($char)
{
    global $map;

    return sprintf('%06s', decbin($map[$char]));
}

function bytesToInt(array $bytes)
{
    $bytes = array_values($bytes);

    $int = (int) ($bytes[3]<<24) | ($bytes[2]<<16) | ($bytes[1]<<8) | ($bytes[0]);

    if ($int >= 2147483648) {
        $int -= 4294967296;
    }

    return $int;
}

$message = $argv[1];
$length = strlen($message);

if ($length > 21) {
    die('nope');
}

echo 'Encoding "'.$message.'" which is '.$length.' bytes long'."\n";

$max = 128;

$joined = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $joined .= encode($message{$i});
}

$length = strlen($joined);
$joined .= str_repeat('0', $max - $length);
$length = strlen($joined);

echo $joined."\n";

$bytes = [];
$position = 0;
$bits = 8;

while ($position < $max) {
    $byte = substr($joined, $position, $bits);
    $bytes[] = bindec($byte);
    $position += $bits;
}

print_r($bytes);

$joined = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i += 4) {
    $int = bytesToInt(array_slice($bytes, $i, 4))."\n";

    echo "Int: {$int}\n";
    $back = unpack("C*", pack("L", $int));
    print_r($back);

    foreach ($back as $byte) {
        $joined .= sprintf('%08s', decbin($byte));
    }
}

echo $joined."\n";

$map = array_flip($map);
print_r($map);
$position = 0;
$message = '';
while ($position < $max) {
    $dec = bindec(substr($joined, $position, 6));
    if ($dec === 0) {
        break;
    }
    $char = $map[$dec];
    $message .= $char;
    $position += 6;
}

echo $message."\n";
```

The code currently allows for 21 characters of set [0-9A-za-z ] to encode in to an integer between -2147483647 and 2147483647.

I suspect the 21 char limit will obviously have to be reduced to around 10 or 11 chars based on the new requirements, which is satisfactory for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is way too much code.

Not only for this question, but if you mentioned in your previous question that you only needed to store 10 or 11 alphanumeric characters in 4 integers of 32 bits, or shortly, 16 bytes, you wouldn't have needed the encoding into 6 bytes altogether, as 11 < 16.

Just store the ASCII values of the characters in a byte array and convert that to 4 integers.

The most significant bit of an integer is the sign bit, which makes the integer negative when set (1). Using the ASCII value of the characters, which all will be < 127, this bit, bearing the value of 128, will never be set.